# How to create a list of tuples Python?

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to create a list of tuples in this format :

```
train = [
    ('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
    ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
    ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
    ('This is my best work.', 'pos'),
    ("What an awesome view", 'pos'),
    ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
    ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
    ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
    ('He is my sworn enemy!', 'neg'),
    ('My boss is horrible.', 'neg')
]
```

So basically I have a for loop which returns a string and I want to add a 'pos' or 'neg' to this string and create a list of these tuples.

I have tried different combinations but still not the result I want. Any hint will be much appreciated

This is my code :

```
if classifier.positiv > classifier.negativ:
   word = (input_text , 'pos')
else: 
   word = (input_text , 'neg')


nbTrain.extend(word)
nbTrain = tuple(nbTrain)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do:

```
nbTrain = []

if classifier.positiv > classifier.negativ:
    word = (input_text , 'pos')
else: 
    word = (input_text , 'neg')


nbTrain.append(word)
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. You are a life saver ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
train = [(input_text, 'pos') if is_positive(input_text) else (input_text, 'neg') for input_text in datasource]
```

Comment: You can make it a little bit shorter: `[(input_text, 'pos' if is_positive(input_text) else 'neg') for input_text in datasource]`  You don't need to reference `input_text` twice.

Comment: very true! I like your's more.